# run command on user display as root isn't working as expected

Tags: shell-script, root, display, x-server, xdotool

I'm trying to execute a `xdotool` operation (move mouse) on the user's display from a root shell but I get:

```
# DISPLAY=:0 mousemove_relative 1 1
No protocol specified
Error:Can't open display: (null)
Failed creating new xdo instance
#
```

Why does this not work?

---

**the script:**

```
#!/bin/bash

exec=`/usr/sbin/nethogs -t -c 1| awk '/smbd/ {print $2}'`

sent=$exec

echo "result: "$sent
sent=$(echo "($sent+0.5)/1" | bc)
echo "rounded: "$sent
if [[ $sent -gt 0 ]]
then 
    echo "music is playing"
    `DISPLAY=:0 xdotool mousemove_relative 1 1`
else
    echo "quiet"
fi
```

---

I get this in `/var/mail/root`:

```
Waiting for first packet to arrive (see sourceforge.net bug 1019381)
result: 6.73438
rounded: 7
music is playing
No protocol specified
Error: Can't open display: (null)
Failed creating new xdo instance
```

Comment: I suggest to use user which owns this X11 session.

Comment: Yes, but I have to run this script as root for reasons that will be out of scope of the question asked...

Comment: Is `mousemove_relative` a shell script or function? If so, can you show the contents to us?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick it's a script, please see above, it'll run as a cront job from `root`'s table

Answer (score 8):

I found the answer on https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/2clob0/help_with_cron_though_its_probably_not_really_a/?st=j7e4jv37&sh=e83bf930

I had to add the following to the script:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
export XAUTHORITY=/home/username/.Xauthority
```